# Why don't my class styles apply to dynamically created elements? Angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, dom, sass

My question is simple; why don't my class styles apply to dynamically created elements?

I am creating a search bar here where I generate an li per matching result, and append it to my ul. When I inspect the page, I see the classes are applied to the li's correctly, but the styles from the class itself aren't present. I hard coded a test li and it had the expected styles. What am I missing here in order to have my styles applied to these dynamically generated elements? Surely I don't have to assign every style for the li's in my typescript? Any explanation would be lovely, thank you all! (:

My HTML:

```
<div class="section">
  <h2>Step 1: Choose an Identity Provider (IDP)</h2>
  <div class="search">
    <input
      class="focusable"
      (focusout)="handleFocusOut()"
      (input)="debounce(search, 300, $event)"
      placeholder="Select Identity Provider"
      autocomplete="off"
    />
    <i class="icon fas fa-search"></i>
    <ul id="search-options">
      <li class="focusable testing">IMG Salesforce</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>-->
</div>
```

My scss:

```
.section {
...
    .search {
      position: relative;
      width: 300px;
      .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 5px;
        top: 3px;
      }
      input {
        width: 300px;
      }
      ul {
        color: red;
        li {
          cursor: pointer;
          &:hover {
            background-color: grey;
            color: red;
          }
          .testing {
              cursor: pointer;
            &:hover {
              background-color: grey;
              color: red;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

My TS:

```
let ul = document.getElementById('search-options');
this.displayServices.forEach((service) => {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.classList.add('focusable', 'testing');
  li.addEventListener('focusout', this.handleFocusOut);
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.getImgUrl(service);
  img.width = 20;
  img.height = 20;
  img.style.margin = '0 10px';

  li.innerHTML = `${service.name}`;
  li.style.display = 'flex';
  li.style.alignItems = 'center';
  li.style.border = '.5px solid black';
  li.style.padding = '8px 0';
  li.prepend(img);
  ul.appendChild(li);
});
```

Comment: 1. This is angular, not angularJS  and 2. Why are you manipulating the DOM like that? Angular has many built in methods to do what you're trying to do - and you should be using them so that your shadow DOM stays up to date. 3. Angular generally creates custom classNames for CSS classes. Your SCSS and HTML might show a 'focusable' class on an element, but when it renders it might be `ng_focusable_1234`. If you create elements manually like you are (an Angular no-no) you can't take advantage of that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be precise without seeing the whole tamale, but generally you should be getting your data in the .TS file and sending that data directly to the view. Your view should be creating those elements on the fly. Not shown in the answer here is the inline styles you were adding to the image and the LI tag - just do those in CSS.

Something like this:

TS:

```
this.someService.getData.subscribe(displayServices => {
  this.displayServices = displayServices;
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="section">
    <h2>Step 1: Choose an Identity Provider (IDP)</h2>
    <div class="search">
      <input
        class="focusable"
        (focusout)="handleFocusOut($event)"
        (input)="debounce(search, 300, $event)"
        placeholder="Select Identity Provider"
        autocomplete="off" />
      <i class="icon fas fa-search"></i>
      <ul id="search-options">
        <li *ngFor="service in displayServices" 
             class="focusable testing"
             (focusout)="handleFocusOut($event)">
            <img [src]="getImgUrl(service)" />
            {{service.name}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>-->
  </div>
```

Comment: I should have also mentioned that I am pretty new to Angular. Thank you for the suggestion on the best practice as far as letting angular handle the dynamic creation of those elements. I changed my html to include an `*ngFor` and now the correct class styles are being applied. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> the classes are applied to the li's correctly, but the styles from the class itself aren't present

If you mean the `focusable` and `testing` classes, I don't see them in your SCSS.

Comment: good catch, I edited the question to show my attempt to use both element and class styling, but neither worked (: